# Windows 10 Start Menu won't let me type?

Tags: windows-10, performance, start-menu

I have several Windows 10 computers that I use, but one of them, a laptop, won't let me type in the Start Menu; I really needed to be able to type fast yesterday and it wouldn't do anything for the longest time (probably like 2 miniutes) I have the same through with this laptop often, it's a ThinkPad from Lenovo and it has like 6 GBs of ram, I can't figure out why it does this, and the crappy Dell I have at home has 4 GBs of ram and never does it.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/722

Comment: I've experienced this before and the second method listed here worked for me: https://appuals.com/fix-windows-10-cant-type-in-search/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.

To fix, see if SFC and DISM will work. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

SFC /SCANNOW and allow it to complete.  Then
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

Restart and test.

If these steps do not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my build of Windows 10 and I no longer have the issue.